# How to alter the HTML table <td> element using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I am trying to create a web app schedule. To do this, I am using the table HTML element to display the day's schedule. The data comes from asp.net API, which feeds it a start time and end time. I need jQuery to take in the data to convert the table cells to the color red to show that there is a task that needs to be done on the schedule. For now, I am simply trying to get JQuery to change the background color of one cell in a table, however, when i run the website, nothing happens.

I have used jQuery append(), replaceWith() and replaceAll() methods. I then added "contenteditable" on the table cell.

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>Student</th>
    <th>8:00am</th>
    <th>8:30am</th>
    <th>9:00am</th>
    <th>9:30am</th>
    <th>10:00am</th>
    <th>10:30am</th>
    <th>11:00am</th>
    <th>11:30am</th>
    <th>12:00pm</th>
    <th>12:30pm</th>
    <th>1:00pm</th>
    <th>1:30pm</th>
    <th>2:00pm</th>
    <th>2:30pm</th>
    <th>3:00pm</th>
    <th>3:30pm</th>
    <th>4:00pm</th>
    <th>4:30pm</th>
    <th>5:00pm</th>
    <th>5:30pm</th>
    <th>6:00pm</th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>       
    <td id="r1t8:00"></td>
    <td id="r1t8:30"></td>
    <td id="r1t9:00"></td>
    <td id="r1t9:30"></td>
    <td id="r1t10:00"></td>
    <td id="r1t10:30"></td>
    <td contenteditable id='r1t11:00'></td>
    <td id="r1t11:30"></td>
    <td id="r1t12:00"></td>
    <td id="r1t12:30"></td>
    <td id="r1t1:00"></td>
    <td id="r1t1:30"></td>
    <td id="r1t2:00"></td>
    <td id="r1t2:30"></td>
    <td id="r1t3:00"></td>
    <td id="r1t3:30"></td>
    <td id="r1t4:00"></td>
    <td id="r1t4:30"></td>
    <td id="r1t5:00"></td>
    <td id="r1t5:30"></td>
    <td id="r1t6:00"></td>
</tr>

</table>


@section scripts
{
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#r1t11:00').replaceWith('<td id="r1t6:00" bgcolor="#FF0000"></td>');
        });
```

This is what I get [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q6OV.png)

I should be getting this [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0ByA.png)

Comment: `bgcolor` is not a valid HTML attribute. Try with `style="background-color:#FF0000;"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help. I found out that the reason why it doesn't work is that the selector doesn't seem to like ":", when I got rid of it, then it worked. My code now is with the id of "r1t_1100" rather than "r1t11:00".

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#r1t_1100").replaceWith("<td bgcolor='#FF0000' id='r1t_1100'></td>");     
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `css` property.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#r1t11:00').css('background-color','#FF0000');
});
```

EDIT: If you generally want to change an attribute, you can use the `attr()` method instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#r1t11:00').attr('rowspan','2');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class(eg: highlight) with appropriate styling to the td's that need to be highlighted rather than doing it on each cells id.

**But if the contenteditable attribute is present for all instances of cells that can be edited - you can then use that to set the class using the attribute selector in css - no JS required.**

```css
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
}

td[contenteditable] {
 background: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>Student</th>
    <th>8:00am</th>
    <th>8:30am</th>
    <th>9:00am</th>
    <th>9:30am</th>
    <th>10:00am</th>
    <th>10:30am</th>
    <th>11:00am</th>
    <th>11:30am</th>
    <th>12:00pm</th>
    <th>12:30pm</th>
    <th>1:00pm</th>
    <th>1:30pm</th>
    <th>2:00pm</th>
    <th>2:30pm</th>
    <th>3:00pm</th>
    <th>3:30pm</th>
    <th>4:00pm</th>
    <th>4:30pm</th>
    <th>5:00pm</th>
    <th>5:30pm</th>
    <th>6:00pm</th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>       
    <td id="r1t8:00"></td>
    <td id="r1t8:30"></td>
    <td id="r1t9:00"></td>
    <td contenteditable id="r1t9:30"></td>
    <td id="r1t10:00"></td>
    <td id="r1t10:30"></td>
    <td contenteditable id='r1t11:00'></td>
    <td id="r1t11:30"></td>
    <td id="r1t12:00"></td>
    <td id="r1t12:30"></td>
    <td id="r1t1:00"></td>
    <td id="r1t1:30"></td>
    <td id="r1t2:00"></td>
    <td id="r1t2:30"></td>
    <td id="r1t3:00"></td>
    <td id="r1t3:30"></td>
    <td id="r1t4:00"></td>
    <td id="r1t4:30"></td>
    <td id="r1t5:00"></td>
    <td id="r1t5:30"></td>
    <td id="r1t6:00"></td>
</tr>

</table>
```